# Android Big Game Files

Tags: android

Is there a tutorial or example somewhere of how you set up the server and ingame activities so that an .apk can download the actual game files?  I have never done anything like this, but I am working on a game that is going to bigger than 50mb and just need some direction.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you simply download it to the users sd card? Shouldn't be that hard?

Comment: Just fire up an HTTP connection and download the content directly to the SD card (don't try to suck it into a byte array or anything first). For files that large, be sure to give the user a warning if they're trying to download over 3G (vs Wifi).

Comment: Just as another suggestion to build on debraceys comment you will probably need something like AsyncTask to handle the download and to help you update a progressbar with how far the downloads are.